# Prove that $\tan \left(\frac{3\pi}{11}\right)+4\sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{11}\right)=\sqrt {11}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\tan \left(\frac{3\pi}{11}\right)+4\sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{11}\right)=\sqrt {11}$$

Hints please !

Comment: and your attempt is?