# Evaluation of trigonometric function without complex numbers

Tags: trigonometry

### We are asked to prove $$\tan{\frac{3\pi}{11}} +4\sin{\frac{2\pi}{11}}=\sqrt{11}$$

So far the solution that I have come across all use complex numbers to get to the result

I am searching for a solution which uses basic trig identities to prove the result

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804283/prove-that-tan-left-frac3-pi11-right4-sin-left-frac2-pi11-right

Comment: I have seen that post.However I am searching for a solution which does not use complex numbers

Comment: Trigonometry is not complete without complex numbers.

Comment: Your right it isn't. I found this problem in a pure trigonometric identities chapter of my study material and i have not completed complex number as yet .So I am hoping that there is a solution without complex numbers